# In Firebase Firestore, is there an advantage to using the docRef pattern that is often shown in the docs?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In the Firestore documentation (and other Firebase docs as well) they tend to set a reference to an item (collection or sometimes document) in a variable, then use that reference to create/update the data on the item.

Here's a copy/paste from the Firestore docs with `citiesRef` as an example.

```
var citiesRef = db.collection("cities");

citiesRef.doc("SF").set({
    name: "San Francisco", state: "CA", country: "USA",
    capital: false, population: 860000,
    regions: ["west_coast", "norcal"] });
citiesRef.doc("LA").set({
    name: "Los Angeles", state: "CA", country: "USA",
    capital: false, population: 3900000,
    regions: ["west_coast", "socal"] });
```

Is there a technical advantage to Firestore in setting it up like this? (Aside from saving the code repetition of the value of the `citiesRef` variable.)

More specifically, is this saving multiple hits to Firestore or the collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not saving any write or read hits. The only advantage should be code reusability and readability.

The example you gave will result in two write hits.

Comment: So it's not doing any black-box batching which is kind of what I figured. Top shelf response, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> More specifically, is this saving multiple hits to Firestore or the collection?

It's all about how you declare the references. Using `db.collection()` every time instead of declaring such variable won't charge you any extra cost.

You are not charged for just creating a reference to a collection or document.
You are charged for read and writes when you use `get()` or `set()` respectively or any other operations that actually read from Firestore or write data.

Comment: I wasn't concerned about the charges, but I can see how it appeared that way. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @monsto it's just more cleaner to declare var once. You can also declare that in a references file and export then from there.